# Индукционная переменная для компилятора

Tags: c++, компиляция

Здравствуйте, уважаемые. Наткнувшись на дальнейший текст,  [вот этот](http://ssd.sscc.ru/sites/default/files/content/attach/317/optimizationsinthecompiler.pdf) (pdf file, 4 page), меня заинтересовало предпоследнее предложение, из уже мною приведённого отрывка. Я хотел бы получить рекомендации о литературе которую мне стоило бы в данной ситуацие почитать. Полагаю: по той же теме, что и в приложение [1](http://ssd.sscc.ru/sites/default/files/content/attach/317/optimizationsinthecompiler.pdf).

> Индукционные переменные часто используются для вычисления адресов
>   элементов массива. Например:
>
> ```
>  struct S1 { double a; double b; }; 
>  S1 list[100]; 
>  int i; 
>  for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) { 
>    list[i].a = 1.0; 
>    list[i].b = 2.0; 
>  }
> ```
>
> Для доступа к элементу массива list компилятор  должен вычислить его
>   адрес. Адрес элемента list[i] равен адресу начала  массива list  плюс
>   i*sizeof(S1). Это линейная функция от  i,  которая может  быть
>   вычислена  с  помощью  индукционной  переменной. Компилятор  может 
>   использовать  одну  и  ту  же индукционную переменную для доступа к
>   list[i].a и list[i].b. Он также может устранить i и использовать
>   индукционную  переменную  как  счетчик  цикла,  если  финальное 
>   значение  индукционной переменной вычислить заранее. Получается
>   следующий код:
>
> ```
> struct S1 { double a; double b; }; 
> S1 list[100], *temp; 
> for (temp = &list[0]; temp < &list[100]; temp++) { 
>   temp->a = 1.0; 
>   temp->b = 2.0; 
> }
> ```
>
> Тот  факт,  что  sizeof(S1)=16,  скрыт в  коде за  синтаксисом С++. 
>   Целочисленным  представлением выражения  &list[100] является 
>   (int)(&list[100])  =  (int)(&list[0]+100*16),  и  temp++  на  самом 
>   деле добавляет 16 к целочисленному представлению temp.
>
> *Компилятору  нет необходимости  исользовать  индукционные перменные 
>   для  вычисления  адресов элементов массива простых типов, потому что
>   процессор имеет аппаратную поддержку для вычисления адреса  элемента 
>   массива,  если  адрес  может  быть  представлен  как  базовый  адрес 
>   плюс  индекс, умноженный на один из множителей: 1, 2, 4 или 8.*
>
> Если бы a и b в примере были типа float, а не double, тогда sizeof(S1)
>   было бы 8, и индукционной переменной бы не понадобилось, потому что
>   процессор имеет аппаратную поддержку для умножения индекса на 8.

Comment: А почему так трудно это предложение написать в виде вопроса, а не отправлять нас искать по ссыльке?

Comment: я не совсем понимаю вопрос, но https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler не это ли вы ищете? там заодно и ссылки. По оптимизации циклов там вообще целый подраздел.

Comment: К тексту статьи много вопросов, вы понимаете о чем пишете?

Comment: Почитайте несколько руководств по ISA (Instruction Set Architecture) для *разных* систем

Comment: Кривой перевод.

Induct -- вовлекать, ввводить, ...

Induction variables -- это временные переменные, которые порождаются компилятором и используются в процессе выполнения промежуточных операций. Например, есть архитектуры, ячейки памяти которых не могут, например, инвертироваться -- значение из ячейки нужно загрузить в регистр, инвертировать регистр, записать содержимое регистра назад в ячейку. Вот этот регистр и есть "induction variable".